# Does the O_DIRECT flag bypass the Linux page cache when accessing block devices too?

Tags: linux-kernel, kvm

I am running a lot of KVM virtual machines, which open the hard disk image  with the **`O_DIRECT`** flag.

I understand, according to the `open()` man page, that using `O_DIRECT` will try to bypass the Linux page cache when writing to a file, but does that apply to block devices as well? (for instance when the hard disk image is a LVM volume, or a ZFS zvol)

NB: the use case of `O_DIRECT` here, is that the guest is already maintaining its own page cache, so it makes no sense to duplicate that on the host.

Answer (score 1):

And it seems the answer is yes: opening a block device with O_DIRECT will bypass the page cache as well.
I found the answer in this 2009 [blog post about the Linux Page Cache](https://manybutfinite.com/post/page-cache-the-affair-between-memory-and-files/) .

> It’s possible to bypass the page cache using O_DIRECT in Linux or
> NO_BUFFERING in Windows, something database software often does.

Comment: please update the answer with a valid source. the embedded link is broken

Comment: I found a correct, better link.